# Enable API Gateway IPv6 on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ipv6

I'm using Lambda and API Gateway for building the APIs. And, I read that AWS CloudFront has IPv6 support. I want to use custom domain and I created certificates with ACM as required by the API Gateway.

But, when I test if the AAAA records are found for the CloudFront URL using http://ready.chair6.net, the AAAA records are not found.

Many blog posts assume CloudFront distribution settings are accessible. But, when we create the CloudFront distribution with API Gateway, you can't change settings of the distribution - not from the console.

How do I enable IPv6 for API Gateway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create your own CloudFront distribution, enable IPv6 there, and then point it to API Gateway -- which you will want to deploy using a Regional Endpoint (which avoids having API Gateway creating its own CloudFront distribution) instead of an Edge-Optimized Endpoint (which creates a "hidden" CloudFront distribution controlled by API Gateway).

Comment: The URL that we get after deploying a stage is not enough..? Should we go ahead and create a custom domain map and then use that domain in CloudFront?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed you'd want to use the URL for the stage as the Origin Domain Name in the CloudFront configuration, and then set your own domain as the Alternate Domain Name for the distribution itself.